# How to: Social Media Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, social-networking, nuget-package

I was tasked to create a new Website - to make it similar to Facebook. ( were talking without games) so a standart backend with CMS for media sites.

> I am familiar with VS'12, asp.net MVC3 & 4 C# or Vb.net , html5 and other languages and feel fit to start this.

**What i wanted to know is if there is any Template, Backends, Nuget Packages, Open Source Applications out there for Visual Studio so I don't have to recreate the wheel?**

- *I have looked where i know to look so a great answer would be a Template, Backend, Nuget Package and where you found it. Or possibly another method of getting started that i didn't list / am not aware of*
- *Please do not come back at me with any PHP templates, for i would not be interested in it.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a good question, but I fear that it's incredibly hard to answer here; Please read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @RussC I understand that Russ I was just curious if someone did actually have a template that they were willing to share. In Your opinion should i delete this question then?

Comment: And if not all then a `No , there isnt one, because of this reason.` would be also great for an aswer.

Comment: I feel it is a valid question and would be interesting to know if there something in the market out there already.

Comment: @Somya Thanks for the support! Also if there isn't anything would be nice so i can possibly build an open source version.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a 'standard social media site'?  The selling point for most of the major ones is that they're unique, providing the same necessary services in their own way, each seeking to do it in the way which fits best into people's heads.

Comment: Yeah okay, maybe not a "standard scoial media site", however the "standart backend with CMS for media sites" ? - ill change this above aswell

Comment: I must say questions being closed in this way on Stack Overflow is really frustrating. Maybe Stack Exchange needs to set up a place for these questions to go and just move them there rather than closing them. I don't know of another forum or online community better suited for these questions that keep getting closed. What, Quora? LOL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look here: [MonoX](http://monox.mono-software.com/)

**Free ASP.NET Content Management and Social Networking Platform**

- MonoX comes with everything you need to build advanced social networks.
- MonoX includes very powerful content management functionality.
- Mono Software provides MonoX blogs, tutorials and support forums.

This is something I'd recommend.